# Issue passing parameters Form::Open Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Fairly new at Laravel and trying to grasp the store function and routing. I'm getting the following error trying to open a form in Laravel:

```
Missing required parameters for [Route: {$route->getName()}] [URI: {$route->uri()}].
```

The issue is because my url is:

```
/projects/1/documents/create
```

And I'm opening to:

```
/projects/1/documents
```

I'm trying to pass the projects ID but I'm missing something.

Form Call:

```
{!! Form::open(['route'=>'projects.documents.store', $project->id]) !!}
     @include('pages.projects.documents.charter.partials._form', ['submitButtonText'=>'Create Project Charter'])
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

My Web Route (I'm assuming the issue is here):

```
// Resource route for Project Document Controller
Route::resource('projects.documents', 'Project\DocumentController');
```

My DocumentController store function:

```
public function store(Request $request, Project $project)
{
    // Validate the request
}
```

I'm not sure if there is any other sections of code that are need. The page renders fine without Form::open and $project->id echo's out correctly.

Edit:

I figured out my issue, it was somewhat silly. Just not use to Laravel formatting yet. The route & param needed to be in an array. The correct formatting is:

```
{!! Form::open(['route'=>array('projects.documents.store', $project->id)]) !!}
```

Comment: Can you include the output of 'php artisan route:list' please? Copy only the routes related to your projects.documents resource.

Comment: Added what you asked for I believe.

Comment: Should I delete this question seeing as I answered it myself?

Comment: I think you might be missing a square braket in your form open. Check this: Form::open(['route' => ['projects.documents.store', $project->id]])

Comment: Ahh, just commented that haha I'm not sure if you should leave it!